# Windows phone 8.1 Make AutosuggestBox Push content downwards

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want the Listview inside the AutoSuggestBox to push content in my grid.  I can't remove the "Popup" item in the base style because the control stops working.

how can i achieve this without rolling my own control?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: I have a suggestBox and below that, i have many textboxes and texblocks. I want the AutoSuggestBox suggestion list to "push" the content down, not overlapp it